# Retrieve/get back command callback function from TKinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I am (for some elaborate setup reasons) trying to retrieve the actual `command` callback function from tkinter widgets, for example setting up a callback for a button `b`

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text='btn', command=lambda:print('foo'))
```

both

```py
b['command']
b.cget('command')
```

which I think both are equivalent to

```py
b.tk.call(b._w, 'cget', '-command')
```

will only return a string like `"2277504761920<lambda\>"` and not the actual command function. Is there a way to get the actual callback function?

Comment: I don't even know if that is possible. You might want to define the command in a variable and use something like `button.my_command = command` to store the command. Later you can get it from `button.my_command`. Otherwise its a great question but the answer (if there is an answer) will involve calling a function from `_tkinter` (maybe?)

Comment: Store the function in a list? And then just call it, or a variable is fine, since its `lambda`.

Comment: The problems is that wraps the command in the `tk.CallWrapper` class and only stores it as a string. The actual command is passed into `tk._tkinter`. I don't have the source code for `tk._tkinter` so the only other way to recover command would be to get all of the `CallWrapper` objects that have been instantiated and look for your function there.

Comment: Found a solution. I will type the answer now

Comment: I guess you just could use `b.invoke` which is equivalent to the command.

Comment: `Misc.tk.createcommand` function is used to create callback commands and which are then stored in a list `Misc._tclCommands` as strings. There is also `Misc.tk.deletecommand` function which is used to unregister and delete commands. But there is no get command method which makes it unlikely to get a callable function back.

Comment: @Saad that is why I had to go through python's memory using the `gc` library and find all of the `CallWrapper` object out of it. It still have a problem with there being multiple `CallWrapper`s attached to 1 widget.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I like your solution but it can be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `tkinter.__init__.py`:

```py
class BaseWidget:
    ...
    def _register(self, func, subst=None, needcleanup=1):
        """Return a newly created Tcl function. If this
        function is called, the Python function FUNC will
        be executed. An optional function SUBST can
        be given which will be executed before FUNC."""
        f = CallWrapper(func, subst, self).__call__
        name = repr(id(f))
        try:
            func = func.__func__
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        try:
            name = name + func.__name__
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.tk.createcommand(name, f)
        if needcleanup:
            if self._tclCommands is None:
                self._tclCommands = []
            self._tclCommands.append(name)
        return name
```

and

```py
class CallWrapper:
    """Internal class. Stores function to call when some user
    defined Tcl function is called e.g. after an event occurred."""
    def __init__(self, func, subst, widget):
        """Store FUNC, SUBST and WIDGET as members."""
        self.func = func
        self.subst = subst
        self.widget = widget
    def __call__(self, *args):
        """Apply first function SUBST to arguments, than FUNC."""
        try:
            if self.subst:
                args = self.subst(*args)
            return self.func(*args)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            self.widget._report_exception()
```

We get that tkinter wraps the function in the `CallWrapper` class. That means that if we get all of the `CallWrapper` objects we can recover the function. Using @hussic's suggestion of monkey patching the `CallWrapper` class with a class that is easier to work with, we can easily get all of the `CallWrapper` objects.

This is my solution implemented with @hussic's suggestion:

```py
import tkinter as tk

tk.call_wappers = [] # A list of all of the `MyCallWrapper` objects

class MyCallWrapper:
    __slots__ = ("func", "subst", "__call__")

    def __init__(self, func, subst, widget):
        # We aren't going to use `widget` because that can take space
        # and we have a memory leak problem
        self.func = func
        self.subst = subst
        # These are the 2 lines I added:
        # First one appends this object to the list defined up there
        # the second one uses lambda because python can be tricky if you
        # use `id(<object>.<function>)`.
        tk.call_wappers.append(self)
        self.__call__ = lambda *args: self.call(*args)

    def call(self, *args):
        """Apply first function SUBST to arguments, than FUNC."""
        try:
            if self.subst:
                args = self.subst(*args)
            return self.func(*args)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            if tk._default_root is None:
                raise
            else:
                tk._default_root._report_exception()

tk.CallWrapper = MyCallWrapper # Monkey patch tkinter

# If we are going to monkey patch `tk.CallWrapper` why not also `tk.getcommand`?
def getcommand(name):
    for call_wapper in tk.call_wappers:
        candidate_name = repr(id(call_wapper.__call__))
        if name.startswith(candidate_name):
            return call_wapper.func
    return None

tk.getcommand = getcommand


# This is the testing code:
def myfunction():
    print("Hi")

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=myfunction)
button.pack()

commandname = button.cget("command")
# This is how we are going to get the function into our variable:
myfunction_from_button = tk.getcommand(commandname)
print(myfunction_from_button)

root.mainloop()
```

As @hussic said in the comments there is a problem that the list (`tk.call_wappers`) is only being appended to. THe problem will be apparent if you have a `.after` tkinter loop as each time `.after` is called an object will be added to the list. To fix this you might want to manually clear the list using `tk.call_wappers.clear()`. I changed it to use the `__slots__` feature to make sure that it doesn't take a lot of space but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Seems pretty deep, think `tkinter` needs to add something for this built in.

Comment: @CoolCloud I agree but most of the time you don't need to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this works but is a bit expensive so just storing the obj reference for now, but accepting it until there is another way to achieve it.

Comment: You can override tk.CallWrapper with your own class, it is an hack but it works.

Comment: @hussic That is a great idea. I hope you don't mind me using it to change my answer

Comment: @TheLizzard, no problem, i think you can also do a `myclass(tk.CallWrapper)` and override only `__init__()`.

Comment: @hussic Yes but that would mean that I am overriding a tkinter class with my own one that inherits from that class. I have no idea how python would deal with it. Also the actual code for the class isn't that much. That is why I decided to just copy/paste the original code changing the `__init__` method.

Comment: There is a problem with this patch: memory leak. tk.call_wappers is never deleted and every python function is wrapped by tkinker, also functions used with .after() which often are re-called forever. There is a solution but requires to patch many tk functions.

Comment: @hussic it isn't going to be that big of a problem and I have a bit of a fix (using `__slots__`). First time I hear memory leak when using Python :D

Comment: @hussic I am only storing 3 `PyObjects*` will only take 24 bytes per `MyCallWrapper` object

Comment: I'll say that the user should clear the list manually.

Comment: @hussic Well that is one option but it isn't going to have that many items anyways. The only problem is that I am using a linear search which has `O(n)`. The space complexity is also `O(n)` which isn't that bad as long as you don't have more than 200 bindings/after scripts/callbacks. The only problem I can think of is if the user uses a tkinter loop made from `.after` scripts. I will edit my answer with a note.

Comment: I have posted a more complex solution that does not leak. @TheLizzard

Comment: You can get instances of `CallWrapper` without having to monkeypatch it. I've provided an example using `gc.get_objects` along with `isinstance`.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot imagine any case and Im not sure at all if this answers your question but it maybe equivalent for what you are looking for:

---

The `invoke` method of the button seems pretty equivalent to me. So **solution-1** would be:

```
import tkinter as tk

def hi():
    print('hello')

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text='test', command=hi)
b.pack()

cmd = b.invoke
#cmd = lambda :b._do('invoke')
root.mainloop()
```

---

If this isnt what you looking for you could call the function in tcl level. **Solution-2**:

```
import tkinter as tk

def hi():
    print('hello')

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text='test', command=hi)
b.pack()
cmd = lambda :root.tk.call(b['command'])
#cmd= lambda :root.tk.eval(b['command'])
cmd()
root.mainloop()
```

---

**Solution 3**, would be to `return` your function by `invoke`:

```
import tkinter as tk

def hi():
    print('hello')
    return hi

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text='test', command=hi)
b.pack()
cmd = b.invoke()
print(cmd) #still a string but comparable
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a more complex solution. It patches `Misc._register`, `Misc.deletecommand` and `Misc.destroy` to delete values from `dict` tkinterfuncs. In this example there are many print to check that values are added and removed from the dict.

```py
import tkinter as tk

tk.tkinterfuncs = {} # name: func

def registertkinterfunc(name, func):
    """Register name in tkinterfuncs."""
    # print('registered', name, func)
    tk.tkinterfuncs[name] = func
    return name

def deletetkinterfunc(name):
    """Delete a registered func from tkinterfuncs."""
    # some funcs ('tkerror', 'exit') are registered outside Misc._register
    if name in tk.tkinterfuncs:
        del tk.tkinterfuncs[name]
        # print('delete', name, 'tkinterfuncs len:', len(tkinterfuncs))

def _register(self, func, subst=None, needcleanup=1):
    """Return a newly created Tcl function. If this
    function is called, the Python function FUNC will
    be executed. An optional function SUBST can
    be given which will be executed before FUNC."""
    name = original_register(self, func, subst, needcleanup)
    return registertkinterfunc(name, func)

def deletecommand(self, name):
    """Internal function.
    Delete the Tcl command provided in NAME."""
    original_deletecommand(self, name)
    deletetkinterfunc(name)

def destroy(self):
    """
    Delete all Tcl commands created for
    this widget in the Tcl interpreter.
    """
    if self._tclCommands is not None:
        for name in self._tclCommands:
            # print('- Tkinter: deleted command', name)
            self.tk.deletecommand(name)
            deletetkinterfunc(name)
        self._tclCommands = None

def getcommand(self, name):
    """
    Gets the command from the name.
    """
    return tk.tkinterfuncs[name]


original_register = tk.Misc.register
tk.Misc._register = tk.Misc.register = _register 
original_deletecommand = tk.Misc.deletecommand
tk.Misc.deletecommand = deletecommand
tk.Misc.destroy = destroy
tk.Misc.getcommand = getcommand

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def f():
        root.after(500, f)

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.after(500, f)
    but1 = tk.Button(root, text='button1', command=f)
    but1.pack()
    but2 = tk.Button(root, text='button2', command=f)
    but2.pack()
    but3 = tk.Button(root, text='button3', command=lambda: print(3))
    but3.pack()
    print(root.getcommand(but1['command']))
    print(root.getcommand(but2['command']))
    print(root.getcommand(but3['command']))
    but3['command'] = f
    print(root.getcommand(but3['command']))
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: btw there are 2 definitions of `_register` in `__init__.py`. The is also one in `Variable._register` you only override `Misc._register`.

Comment: You might want to remove the (debug?) `print`s

Comment: The _register in Variable is used by trace_add. ("Define a trace callback for the variable."). If you need the variable trace, it should be patched also. Yes the prints are for debug, can be removed.

Comment: Why don't you define a function (`getcommand`) and patch it in tkinter to make it easier to get the function? Also can you file it as a feature request to [python](https://bugs.python.org/)?

Comment: Using a dict (`tkinterfuncs`) is easy to find func from name (es. `tkinterfuncs[but1['command']]`). But you are right, can be embedded in tk as you did.

Comment: If you are interested, i have also patched Variable. About Python proposal, if you want to do it is ok for me. English is not my language, should be difficult for me to make it

Comment: English isn't my first language either and I can't submit an issue without making my email public :(

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a command to a widget, or bind a function to an event, the python function is wrapped in a `tkinter.CallWrapper` object. That wrapper contains a reference to the python function along with a reference to the widget. To get a callback for a widget you can iterate over the instances of the wrapper in order to get back the original function.

For example, something like this might work:

```
import tkinter as tk
import gc

def get_callback(widget):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if isinstance(obj, tk.CallWrapper) and obj.widget == widget:
            return obj.func
    return None
```

You can then directly call the return value of this function. Consider the following block of code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import gc

def get_callback(widget):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if isinstance(obj, tk.CallWrapper) and obj.widget == widget:
            return obj.func

def do_something():
    print(f"button1: {get_callback(button1)} type: {type(get_callback(button1))}")
    print(f"button2: {get_callback(button2)} type: {type(get_callback(button2))}")

root = tk.Tk()
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="do_something", command=do_something)
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="lambda", command=lambda: do_something())
button1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
button2.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

When I click either button, I see this in the console output which proves that the `get_callback` method returns a callable.

```
button1: <function do_something at 0x103386040> type: <class 'function'>
button2: <function <lambda> at 0x103419700> type: <class 'function'>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that loop through all of the objects that are in memory including built in functions like `print`, `str`, ... as they are also technically objects `gc` keeps a track of? So if I had a lot of objects then wouldn't your method be slow? It's still going to be very fast but slower than @hussic's solution.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, it loops over every object. No, it's not slow unless you have millions of objects.  I just tested it with 10,000 buttons with callbacks, resulting in over 77,000 python objects to be checked, and it ran in .0016 seconds. That seems plenty fast enough for any real-world scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Button is a object you can assign attributes just define your function outside the button and assign the function ass a attribute

```
func_print = lambda: print("nice")
x = Button(..., command=func_print)
x.my_func = func_print

def something():
    x.my_func()

something()

>>> nice
```

I was looking same problem but I could not find any nice answer then I created mine actually it is very easy